# How to make Raycast 2D detect tilemap correctly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using a Raycast and I'm trying to get it to detect a Tilemap. I have a Ray cast set up like so.

```
 void Update()
 {
     RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.up, 4f);
     Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector2.up * 4f, Color.red);
     if (hit.collider != null)
     {
         if (hit.collider.tag == "CollideLayer")
         {
             Debug.Log(hit.collider.name);
         }
     }
 }
```

I have a Tilemap Collider 2D and a Composite Collider. I want the raycast to detect anytime it hits a wall.

I have a tag set in one of the tilemap, so it only detects the tilemap.

I've tested this code in twice to see if there was any difference. In the initial test, the raycast detects but only from its origin point, and not from anywhere else on the raycast, giving me inconsistent results.

..and in the second test, it wouldn't detect at all.

I want it to detect if any part of the raycast is hit by a part of the tilemap. What am I missing here? Is it possible to detect the tilemap in this way? Any help will be much appreciated.

```
public class BeaconBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {

 public Tilemap map;
 void Update()
 {
     Vector3 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
     Vector3Int mouseToCell = map.WorldToCell(new Vector3(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y, 0));
     Vector3 getCenterCell = map.GetCellCenterWorld(mouseToCell);

     RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(getCenterCell, Vector2.up, 4f);
     Debug.DrawRay(getCenterCell, Vector2.up * 4f, Color.red);

     if (hit.collider != null)
     {
         // Debug.Log("hitting " + hit.collider.name);
         if (hit.collider.tag == "CollideLayer")
         {
             Debug.Log(hit.collider.name);
         }
     }
     transform.position = getCenterCell;
 }

 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
 {
     // Debug.Log(other.gameObject.name);
 }

 private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
 {
     // Debug.Log(other.gameObject.name + " not touching" );
 }}
```

In this example, the behavior is inconsistent, making me think I'm doing something wrong. Any clues or advice about how to fix this, or any ideas and suggestions will be much appreciated.

Edit:

So I decided to continue slowly working this out, and disabled one of the tilemaps collider, I have two tilemaps each with a tilemap collider. When I disable the ground tilemap collider, it seems to work fine when I want to collide with the Walls collider. So perhaps there's something interfering with it. Perhaps it's got something to do with a Layer mask. I'm not sure, I'm going to continue researching.